# Connection string C# is not specified & initialized error

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, database, connection-string

I'm new to .Net development and I'm trying to get some data from local database.

below is the connection string on config file

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="server=.\SQLEXPRESS;database=mkhzn;Integrated Security=SSPI;User Instance=True"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

Below is the view model which calls the Data layer class

```
class EmployeeDetailsVM : Class1
    {
        private EmployeeUI.Employee _employee;
        public EmployeeUI.Employee Employee
        {
            get => _employee;
            set
            {
                _employee = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Employee");
            }
        }

        public EmployeeDetailsVM()
        {
            IEmployeeBL employeeBL = new EmployeeBL.EmployeeBL(new EmployeeDAL.EmployeeDAL());
            Console.WriteLine("I'm connected to DB 2");
            Employee = employeeBL.GetAllEmployees().FirstOrDefault();
            Console.WriteLine("Displayed");
        }
    }
```

and below is the data layer class

```
public class EmployeeDAL : IEmployeeDAL
    {
        
       

        public List<Employee> GetAllEmployees()
        {
            var employees = new List<Employee>();
            string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(constr))
            {
                connection.Open();
                SqlCommand selectCommand = new SqlCommand("Select * from Employee", connection);
                
                Console.WriteLine("I'm connected to DB");
                SqlDataReader reader = selectCommand.ExecuteReader();
                if (reader.HasRows)
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        var employee = new Employee
                        {
                            Employee_ID = reader.GetInt32(0),
                            First_Name = reader.GetString(1),
                            Last_Name = reader.GetString(2),
                            Date_Birth = reader.GetDateTime(3),
                            Street_Address = reader.GetString(4),
                            city = reader.GetString(5),
                            Province = reader.GetString(6),
                            Joining_Date = reader.GetDateTime(7),
                            Resignation_Date = reader.GetDateTime(8)
                        };
                        employees.Add(employee);
                    }
                }
                else { }
                reader.Close();
            }
            return employees;
        }
    }
```

Can someone lead me to a clue for this issue? As you can see I'm initializing the connection string on the above class but when debugging it's showing that no connection string has been initialized.

Comment: So when you put a breakpoint on the `using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(constr))` line, what actually *is* the value of `constr`?

Comment: Also, I wouldn't expect a ViewModel to have that level of connection with the BL; if I were creating a VM it'd pretty much just know about the data items the UI would use.. the BL might know about VMs if there wasn't some interim layer but not the other way round.

Comment: Wouldn't it be `Properties.Resources.ConnectionString`?

Comment: @Caius Jard it's not reaching to the break point.

Comment: How can it not? Where does it go? Debug it

Comment: @CaiusJard it goes to  Employee = employeeBL.GetAllEmployees().FirstOrDefault(); & then it displays the connection string error.

Comment: Well, it will do if you step over. Step Into instead. Or put a breakpoint inside GetAllEmployees